# CakePHP 3.6: Update control value based on the selection of a dropdown control

Tags: php, cakephp, onchange

I have the following tables:

```
customers[id, name, surname, phone, text, balance, created]

service_types[id, title, price, length, is_subscription, created, payment]

customer_service_types[id, customer_id, service_type_id, price, created]
```

And the relations:

**ServiceTypesTable.php:**

```
$this->hasMany('CustomerServiceTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'service_type_id'
    ]);
```

**CustomerServiceTypesTable.php:**

```
$this->belongsTo('Customers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('ServiceTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'service_type_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

In `CustomerServiceTypes\add.ctp` I have a dropdown with the `services` and a field for the price:

```
echo $this->Form->control('customer_id', ['options' => $customers,'label' => 'Customer']);
echo $this->Form->control('service_type_id', ['options' => $serviceTypes, 'label' => 'Service']);
echo $this->Form->control('price', ['label' => 'Price']);
```

In the `CustomerServiceTypesController.php`:

```
public function add($customerid = null)
    {
        $customerServiceType = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $customerServiceType = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->patchEntity($customerServiceType, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->CustomerServiceTypes->save($customerServiceType)) {

                //debug($this->request->getData("customer_id"),true);
                

                $this->Flash->success(__('Success'));

                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'edit', $customerid]);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Fail'));
        }
        $customers = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->Customers->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->where(['Customers.id =' => $customerid]);
        $serviceTypes = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->ServiceTypes->find('list', [
        'valueField' => function ($row) {
            return $row['title'] . ' (Suggested price: ' . $row['price'] . ')';
        }
    ], ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('customerServiceType', 'customers', 'serviceTypes'));
    }
```

Which adds in the `services` dropdown valuefield the value of the specific service:

> Service_1 (Suggested price: 100)
>
> Service_2 (Suggested price: 150)
>
> .....

But what I want to achieve is to update the `price` field with the suggested price when user makes a selection in the dropdown field. Is it possible to achieve that server side? Without the use of javascript? Because my knowledge is very limited in javascript. If not can you provide a working example based on my question?

Comment: do you want to update the price column in `service_types` table on submit?

Comment: @tphobe9312 no I want to update the `price` control (`echo $this->Form->control('price', ['label' => 'Price']);`) on dropdown change

Comment: Without Javascript that's not possible as far as I know. You can achieve this easily by AngularJS.

Comment: @tphobe9312 can you guide me to a js solution then? because I haven't used js before in such context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Following changes:

**add.ctp**

```
    <div ng-app=""  ng-init='servicePrices = <?php echo json_encode($servicePrices); ?>;' >

<?php

echo $this->Form->create();

echo $this->Form->control('customer_id', ['options' => $customers,'label' => 'Customer']);

echo $this->Form->control('service_type_id', [
'options' => $serviceTypes, 'label' => 'Service',
'ng-model'=>'service_type_id'
]);

 echo $this->Form->control('price', [
'label' => 'Price',
'ng-model'=>'servicePrices[service_type_id]'
]);

echo $this->Form->submit('submit');

?>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js" ></script>
```

**CustomerServiceTypesController.php**

```
// add this
 $servicePrices = $this->CustomerServiceTypes
            ->ServiceTypes
            ->find()
            ->limit(200)
            ->combine('id','price');


    $this->set(compact('customerServiceType', 'customers', 'serviceTypes','servicePrices'));
```